# Pycharm and Python Paths on Windows with Conda

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, anaconda, conda

I am working with multiple versions of Python, so I don't want to put any one of them in my windows path. I discovered that I can create a virtualenv (under Settings -> Project: X -> Project Interpreter and that will allow me to specify which python exe to use, but also where to get other useful programs, like pip. The end result is that using Virtualenv I can type "pip" or "python" in the terminal in Pycharm and use it as a regular terminal.

But now I'm working with Anaconda so I don't want to use virtualenv and I want to use conda instead. This works fine, but it doesn't seem to put anything into the path. (This is particularly important because where I intend to keep my project is not near my path to the python environment conda created.)

So if I type "pip" or "python" in the pycharm terminal, it doesn't recognize them. I have to specify a huge path to get it to work right.

I've been googling around and trying to find a solution to this problem. I've found a number of supposed solutions, but so far none have worked.

So, for example, I've already tried Add Content Root under project structure. This does nothing. I've tried add local, which seems to just screw everything up. (Presumably this is a way to create a local environment that I shouldn't be touching in conda.) I've tried adding a PathConfig.pth file. So far nothing works.

Remember, I don't want to add anything into the windows path (which obviously would solve my problem) because then it won't know which specific environment I want at the moment.

Comment: When using conda's environments, you can always do ```activate py2_env``` when there is an environment ```py2_env``` and conda's scripts are in your path. If the latter is not the case, you need to find the activate.bat to do this. This will set all paths in the current terminal. I only tried this in the windows console and unix shell though, no idea if that works within pycharm. If you are calling your program through the terminal (instead of the run button) it should work! [Relevant docs](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html#change-environments-activate-deactivate)

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this. This isn't really what I want though, as then I can't just start using pycharm and start coding, I have to first type in a very very long string of paths and commands that I can't memorize.

Comment: I would be open to this approach, however, if I could somehow set it in Pycharm to every time I open this project it automatically activates the environment. (Which happens automatically in Pycharm when you use a virtualenv instead of conda.)

Comment: Well, you can always add a shortcut/script to your desktop. But you are right, i expect pycharm to do have something nicer (but i don't know of anything and i did't use it for a long time).

Comment: I'm also suffering from this problem.  Despite setting the default interpreter to the python.exe in my correct conda env directory, commands in the PyCharm Python console do not match those in a cmd window after running activate <myenv> and then starting python.  The source of the problem is that the correct PATH environmental variable is only set upon conda activate, not when in the PyCharm console.  How to get PyCharm to activate the conda PATH?  I don't know.